# How to expose a complete tree structure with Spring Data REST and HATEOAS?

Tags: jpa, tree, projection, spring-data-rest, hateoas

I have a JPA tree structure

```
@Entity
public class Document {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int id;
   private String text;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "parent")
   Document parent;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   Set<Document> children;

   (getters and setters)

}
```

and a projection

```
@Projection(name = "all", types = Document.class)
public interface AllDocumentsProjection {

    int getId();
    String getText();
    Set<Document> getChildren();

}
```

When I make a GET request with url

localhost:8080/documents/1?projection=all

I only get the first children of the root document. Not children of the children. Is this possible with projections? Or is there an other way?

Answer (score 4):

```
@Projection(name = "all", types = Document.class)
public interface AllDocumentsProjection {

    int getId();
    String getText();
    Set<AllDocumentsProjection> getChildren();

}
```

This works perfect for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost certain there is no way to recursively embed resources via [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections). Only other thing I think of is to handle this logic manually in the controller :/

Answer (score -1):

Try [excerpts](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.5.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.excerpts).

You should add to your repository definition the `excerptProjection` field like below:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = AllDocumentsProjection.class)
interface DocumentRepository extends CrudRepository<Document, Integer> {}
```